# Is there any way to load css and javascript from a string?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I've seen many examples of loading CSS and javascript dynamically from a file.  [Here's a good example](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml).  But is there a way to load CSS or javascript as a string?  For example, something like:

```
var style = ".class { width:100% }"
document.loadStyle(style);
```

Or something of that nature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var javascript = "alert('hello');";
eval(javascript);
```

This will load the JavaScript from a string, but be warned that this is highly insecure and not recommended. If a malicious process ever interfered with your string of JavaScript, it could result in security issues.

As far as CSS goes, you can append a style tag to the page using jQuery, like so:

```
$('head').append("<style>body { background-color: grey; }</style>");
```

Or, for the JavaScript purists:

```
var s = document.createElement("style");
s.innerHTML = "body { background-color:white !important; }";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: More reading: [\[javascript\] \[eval\] evil](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%5Beval%5D+evil)

Answer (score 4):

Another way without using potentially dangerous `eval` and `innerHTML` is creating a `link` element with base64 encoded URL:

```
function loadCSS(cssStyles) {
  const link = document.createElement('link');
  link.href = `data:text/css;base64,${btoa(cssStyles)}`;
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

but, this code work on only single HTML file that contain style tag

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</body>
<script>
    const cssText = `.foo{
            background-color: black;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .bar{
            background-color: gray;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }`
    document.querySelector("style").innerText = cssText;
</script>
</html>```
````