# Is there an equivalent of eval for css styles?

Tags: javascript, css, eval

I have a style element that is loaded from an external resource, and I want to apply it's styles without putting it inline.

For instance `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css" />` will load a css file and apply it's rules without putting it inline and `<script src="zepto.js"></script>` will do the same for javascript.

If you load an external bit of js, you can evaluate it using `eval()` even though that's frowned upon.

But when one loads an external bit of styling, I don't know how to evaluate it except to add it to the dom.

So is there a similar function for styles as eval is to scripts?  Does anyone know a good hack to get the same effect?

Anything is fine as long as the styling applies without it showing up in the dom.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10457877/4774263 take a look at this answer, you can load your style via Jquery, just append your styles to the head

Comment: Why don't you want to put the stylesheet in the DOM tree? Do you want to avoid polluting it?

Comment: _"how to evaluate it"_ What is expected result of evaluation ? Do you want to add or remove portions of `css` text before appending `css` text to `DOM` ?

Comment: The expected result of evaluation is the same as though the stylesheet were linked externally using the link element.

Comment: @BoltClock Not certain if OP is attempting to 1) modify `css` text before appending to `DOM`;  2) access `css` text as an `styleSheet` or other object; 3) view applied `css` text in a `document` , without using current `document` ?

Comment: @guest271314: Why do you keep talking about modifying the CSS? All the OP wants to do is take an existing stylesheet and make its contents affect the page without appending them in a style element. It's that simple. The only thing that is left wanting is why the OP doesn't want to use a style element in the first place, but I'm assuming they have their own reasons...

Comment: @BoltClock _"All the OP wants to do is take an existing stylesheet and make its contents affect the page without appending them in a style element."_ Not gathering the same from Question, but you could be correct. Perhaps OP will chime in

Comment: @BoltClock _"#2 is the opposite of what the OP is trying to accomplish. The OP does want the CSS to take effect, but does not want to add them via a style element to the DOM."_ Could be achieved using `CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()` https://jsfiddle.net/e3vkev6x/ ?

Comment: @guest271314: That *could* be it, if the OP doesn't mind having an empty <style> element in the DOM that they can then insert the CSS into. Note that jsFiddle provides such an element automatically (it's where the contents of the CSS pane go).

Comment: @BoltClock _"Note that jsFiddle provides such an element automatically"_ Yes, not certain which service does not add elements to `document` ; will try plnkr http://plnkr.co

Comment: @BoltClock You are correct. If `style` element is not in `document`, throws error at plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/m4RSCBxokPc3tUKFgITA?p=preview

Comment: woah.  Sorry you guys.  I've never had a question blow up like this.  The reason that I wanted to be able to add css without a style link is simply that I'm also doing an eval in the same function.  If there was a way to make the two act the same, it would be nice just for the sake of keeping their actions parallel.  But appending the style to the head is a totally workable solution for now.  I'd just prefer the way I was saying because it would probably lead me down a path of having more control over page styling.

Comment: it just sort of seemed like if none of the script is included anywhere in the page dom, than neither should the styling.

Sorry I don't have a cooler reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `style` tag add to the `head` and then set your complete css content into `innerHTML`.

Ex:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

//here is the magic.
style.innerHTML = 'put the css content'; 
//Ex: style.innerHTML = '.cssClass { color: #F00; }';
```

Comment: That's what the OP said: "But when one loads an external bit of styling, I don't know how to evaluate it except to add it to the dom." And they don't want this.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the requirement is that dynamically generated/loaded css content has to be applied to the page ( `eval` ) and `css` code shouldn't show up in the page.

Comment: Also OP said: "Anything is fine as long as the styling applies without it showing up in the dom."

Comment: @RoyalPinto _"If I am not wrong, the requirement is that dynamically generated/loaded css content has to be applied to the page ( eval ) and css code shouldn't show up in the page. "_ Does `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style)` append `css` text to `DOM` ?

Comment: @guest271314: It appends a style element to the DOM (you can tell from the first two lines of code). Which, for some reason, is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, OP Could use `XMLHttpRequest` to request `.css` file,  adjust `css` text, then append to `DOM`. Current solution appends `css` text directly to `DOM` at `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style)`, though does not appear to describe how to retrieve external resource, modify or evaluate, before appending `css` text to `DOM` ?

Comment: @guest271314, even if `style` node is added to the `dom` tree, it won't show up in the page.

Comment: @guest271314: The OP already knows how to obtain the contents of the stylesheet and is not interested in how to do that. They are asking how they can evaluate the stylesheet without appending a style element to the DOM.

Comment: OP is trying to avoid `link` tag with reference to a `CSS` file. But this answer does add a style tag dynamically.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` instead of the simpler (and equivalent) [`document.head`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/head)?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. JavaScript CSS parsers. For example Node.js has pure JS CSS parsers, check http://github.com/reworkcss/css for example. I have no idea of its quality though.
2. To add those styles to the DOM as content of `<style>` element and set `style.disabled = true` on it so its rules will not affect current content.

Comment: #2 is the opposite of what the OP is trying to accomplish. The OP *does* want the CSS to take effect, but **does not want to add them via a style element to the DOM**.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, that... It is impossible then. CSS has concept of specificity, one component of it is position of style inclusion in the DOM. Thus you cannot have hanging styles. At all.

Comment: Yeah if the browser's implementation of author-level styles is strictly either from a <link> element or a <style> element then I agree what the OP wants is actually impossible. (By the way, you mean [cascading order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order), not specificity.)