# Is it possible to change CSS string text to css code in a project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to convert the source of the website inside a `String` variable to code and use it.

How can I do this?

```
var cssStr = 'a{text-decoration: none}';

// to css code

a {
   text-decoration: none
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to load css and javascript from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457870/is-there-any-way-to-load-css-and-javascript-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var cssStr = 'a{text-decoration: none} a{color: red}';

let text = document.getElementById('yourId');
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = cssStr;
text.appendChild(style);
```

```html
<a href=# id="yourId"><p> Your Text </p></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have below script:

```
var cssStr = 'a{text-decoration: none}';
let styleTag = document.createElement('style');
styleTag.innerHTML = cssStr;
document.firstChild.appendChild(styleTag);
```

This will basically create `<style></style>` and append it to html.  If you have specific `<style>` tag, select it instead of creating new.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`CSSStyleSheet.insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) is for:

```js
let styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
styleSheet.insertRule('.demo { background: red; color: white; }');
```

```html
<div class="demo">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.cssClass { text-decoration: none; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

element.className = 'cssClass';
```